# Animating two nested Border elements in WPF ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, controltemplate, visualstatemanager

I am tryting to create new ControlTemplate for textbox. At the end it should use several custom states, that changes the appearence of the control. The ControlTemplate in the code snippet is stripped to bone just to ilustrate my problem.

I want to use two nested border elements and animate their borders and background color in various visual states.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border Name="Inner" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush> 
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE8EDF9" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is almost basic example of usage of visualstates in control template that can be found on internet. When comes to mouseover event, is is not working and the background does not change. If I remove the inner border, it will work just as expected.

If anyone is able to help me with this template, I would very much apprecite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that you attached the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` collection to the inner `Border` element, so when you removed the inner `Border`, the `VisualStateGroups` collection became attached to the outer `Border` again, which is why it still worked . All you need to do to fix it is to move it into the outer `Border`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE8EDF9" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border Name="Inner" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: beat me by seconds, and thanks for cleaning up those dependencies for him, it's like nails on a chalkboard seeing all that noise in someones xaml... +1

Comment: *thanks for cleaning up those dependencies for him, it's like nails on a chalkboard*... haha... I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: To complete this answer, know that events are "captured" by the controls you are overing (or any other action you are doing).
What probably happens, is that your second border is capturing the mouseOver event, process it, and then prevents it from tuneling or bubbling. To help you with this kind of issue, try to use a tool like XAMLSpy, to see what really happens at runtime

Comment: Your suggested answer is working miracles for me. Thank you very much. Next time I will be cautious where I attach VisualStateManager.

Comment: Actually, you moved the VisualStateGroups from the inner to the outer border, not the other way round (as you wrote in your answer). And that is exactly where it belongs.

Comment: +1 Hey thanks again @Clemens... you do a great job of catching these mistakes, keep it up. I've updated my answer accordingly.